# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Tags: php, web-services

I am requesting a webservice to pull lat/lng coordinates by using country names from a php file using this code:

```
$defaultcountry = $_REQUEST['country'];
$daurl = "http://ws.geonames.org/search?q=".$defaultcountry.'&rows=5';
$contents = file_get_contents($daurl);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
$lat = $xml->geoname->lat;
$lng = $xml->geoname->lng;

$coords = array('lat'=>"$lat", 'lng'=>"$lng");

$o = array('success'=>true, 'coords'=>$coords);  


echo json_encode($o);
```

i dont have issues calling this file directly from the browser. The problem is when this file is being called by ajax somewhere, like so:

```
ajaxManager.add('cacheQueue',{
                                    url: '../lib/getdefaultcoord.php',
                                    type:'POST',
                                    dataType:'json',
                                    data:{country:Country},
                                    success:function(json){
                                        alert(json.coords.lng);

                                    }

                                    })
```

thus, error comes up as stated on my subject line. I have a similar scenario for requesting countrynames using a different webservice url (webservicex.net). That one from geonames.com does not seem to work when requests are made via ajax... How come?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the **$daurl** variable to ensure your $_REQUEST parameter came through properly?  If this appears fine, next try **file_get_contents()** on a random page like http://www.test.com and see if that has the same issue.

Comment: the whole file actually is working by just typing directly to the address bar the url : ......./lib/getdefaultcoord.php?country=egypt but when i call this file from another file using jquery ajax i get the error stated..

Comment: and when i call this file with ajax i also get the country name properly by just echoing the country param...

Answer (score 0):

Is this URL correct from the page you do the AJAX request?

url: '../lib/getdefaultcoord.php'

Comment: yes that is correct, this one is working fine and is able to fetch results like the way i normally use it: ajaxManager.add({...url:'../lib/getdefaultcoord.php',data:params...});

Answer (score 0):

you should get [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and examine the XHR from it.

I think or your url is wrong or some parameters are not passed like expected

Comment: which url is wrong? i have to of em there.. the ajax requesting file is working properly as it calls the getdefaultcoord outputting the country param if i like to.

Answer (score 0):

im providing something u guys can play if you won't mind:
requesting file with ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


        $.post('getdefaultcoord.php', {country:"united arab emirates"}, function(data){
            alert(data.coords.lat);

        },'json');


    });
```

on getdefaultcoord.php:

```
$defaultcountry = $_REQUEST['country'];
$url = "http://ws.geonames.org/search?q=".$defaultcountry."&rows=5";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
$lat = $xml->geoname->lat;
$lng = $xml->geoname->lng;


$coords = array("lat"=>$lat,"lng"=>$lng);
$o = array('success'=>true, 'coords'=>$coords);

echo json_encode($o);
```

u can play around the getdefaultcoord.php to make sure that the requesting file is working properly with its country request and so goes with the getdefaultcoord.php, notice that the original error i posted on my subject line is the same using firebug...

Answer (score 0):

I think in your ajax call you should try to spell the whole path out for the url.  Instead of using a relative - "../lib/getdefaultcoord.php"  try using "http://www.yourdomain.com/lib/getdefaultcoord.php".  The ajax call could be confused by the relative reference.